# Apache axis: wrong date returned in Calendar object

Tags: calendar, axis

Used Apache axis to consume a WSDL which has a column of `type="xsd:dateTime"`.
In SOAP UI with plain vanilla request, response has -

```
 <UpdateDateTime>2012-05-08T04:58:00</UpdateDateTime>
```

However when using axis consumer, for the same value - l`istOfValues[pos].getUpdateDateTime().getTime()` returns a different time -
`2012-05-07 21:58:00`.
`getUpdateDateTime()` in the above returns instance of java.util.Calendar.

Is it a timezone problem or the 'T' in between is parsed incorrect?
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

How are you displaying the "2012-05-07 21:58:00"? It's almost certainly just a time zone issue. I suspect it's treating 2012-05-08T04:58:00 as a universal time, and applying your local time zone to that. It's hard to say without seeing any code or where your diagnostics have come from, but I'd be surprised if it *weren't* just a time zone issue.

Of course, if you can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `java.util.Date/Calendar`, you can use `LocalDateTime` which is what I suspect is represented here (given the lack of time zone information in the response). I don't know if Axis supports that, but it would be worth looking into.

Comment: Yes, you were right! It takes 2012-05-08T04:58:00 as Central time & adds +5:30 (IST- my local timezone) to it. But the question is even if I run it from local box(case above) or run in remote box (@San Jose) - its adding +5:30 to it. Beats me. Axis doesn't support Joda though.

Comment: @user1004586: I don't see why you think it's regarding it as *central* time. It's still not entirely clear how you're seeing all these values either. If you could give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem (client side) and include the results on the different boxes, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Eclipse debug with date time value in Inspect -

http://i45.tinypic.com/157zpy1.jpg

& the plain request in soap UI gives -

2012-05-08T04:58:00
Bombay,India

Sorry, i meant UTC in my first reply.

Comment: Precisely, the date retrieved from service API gets converted to local timezone's date/time. If client deployed in box with IST, time gets converted to IST; if in box with PST, gets converted accordingly.